# textRectForBounds: Not Called on Custom UITextFields Loaded from Nib

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield

I created a subclass of UITextField that overrides [text|editing|placeholder]RectForBounds: (all with the exact same implementation). Everything works fine when instantiated from code, but not when it's loaded from a nib. On the text fields loaded from the nib, neither the text nor the placeholder is drawn.

I've noticed that none of the RectForBounds methods are called until the user taps the text field; on tap, editing & placeholderRectForBounds are called with the correct bounds size ({{0, 0}, {300, 39}}), while textRectForBounds is called with ({{0, 0}, {100, 100}}).

So, why is the text never drawn (and only on the fields loaded from a nib)? Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug with UITextField?

EDIT:

Here's the code:

```
#import "SearchTextField.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

#define BUTTON_WIDTH 50
#define MAX_LABEL_WIDTH 200

@interface SearchTextField ()

@property(retain, nonatomic) UILabel *label;
@property(retain, nonatomic) UIButton *button;

- (void)i_baseInit;

@end

@implementation SearchTextField

@synthesize title = _title;
@synthesize label = label_;
@synthesize button = button_;
@synthesize showButton = _showButton;
@synthesize backgroundView = _my_backgroundView;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        _showButton = YES;
        [self i_baseInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])
    {
        [self i_baseInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)i_baseInit
{
    self.opaque = NO;
    self.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
    self.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    self.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    _my_backgroundView = [[MyView alloc] init];
    self.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    self.label = [[[UILabel alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold" size:15];
    self.label.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    self.label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
    self.label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.label.text = _title;
    self.leftView = self.label;

    self.button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [self.button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_sm"]
                           forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_sm_pressed"]
                           forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    self.button.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
    self.button.hidden = !_showButton;
    self.rightView = self.button;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    self.backgroundView.frame = CGRectMake(self.bounds.origin.x,
                                           self.bounds.origin.y,
                                           self.bounds.size.width-1, // Without this, the background sticks out 1 pt from the button
                                           self.bounds.size.height);
    [self.backgroundView drawRect:rect];
}

- (id)copy
{
    SearchTextField *copy = [[self.class alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
    copy.text = self.text;
    copy.textAlignment = self.textAlignment;
    copy.textColor = self.textColor;

    copy.placeholder = self.placeholder;

    copy.background = self.background;
    copy.backgroundColor = self.backgroundColor;

    copy.borderStyle = self.borderStyle;
    copy.font = self.font;
    copy.showButton = self.showButton;
    copy.title = self.title;

    copy.delegate = self.delegate;

    copy.secureTextEntry = self.secureTextEntry;

    copy.returnKeyType = self.returnKeyType;
    copy.keyboardType = self.keyboardType;

    return copy;
}

#pragma mark - UITextField Positioning -

- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    CGSize labelSize = [self.label.text sizeWithFont:self.label.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(MAX_LABEL_WIDTH, bounds.size.height)];
    CGSize textSize = [@"Test" sizeWithFont:self.font];
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(10 + labelSize.width,
                      (bounds.size.height-textSize.height)/2,
                      bounds.size.width - (20 + labelSize.width + ((self.showButton) ? BUTTON_WIDTH : 0)),
                      textSize.height);
    return rect;
}

- (CGRect)placeholderRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    return [self textRectForBounds:bounds];
}

- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    return [self textRectForBounds:bounds];
}

- (CGRect)leftViewRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    return CGRectMake(10,
                      0,
                      [self.label.text sizeWithFont:self.label.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(MAX_LABEL_WIDTH, bounds.size.height)].width,
                      bounds.size.height);
}

- (CGRect)rightViewRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    if (!self.showButton) { return CGRectZero; }

    return CGRectMake(bounds.size.width-BUTTON_WIDTH,
                      0,
                      BUTTON_WIDTH,
                      bounds.size.height);
}

#pragma mark -

- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)title
{
    [_title release];
    _title = [title retain];
    self.label.text = title;
    [self setNeedsLayout];
}

- (UIImage *)imageForState:(UIControlState)state
{
    return [self.button imageForState:state];
}

- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state
{
    [self.button setImage:image forState:state];
}

- (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents
{
    [self.button addTarget:target action:action forControlEvents:controlEvents];
}

- (void)setShowButton:(BOOL)showButton
{
    self.button.hidden = !showButton;
    _showButton = showButton;
    [self setNeedsLayout];
}

- (MyView *)backgroundView
{
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
    return _my_backgroundView;
}
- (void)dealloc
{
    [_my_backgroundView release];
    [label_ release];
    [button_ release];

    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: Did you override initWithFrame:? If so you also need to override initiWithCoder:, which is how things get inited by UINib.

Comment: Yes, I did override initWithCoder:. Other than the text, everything looks fine.

Comment: I'll take a look at it tonight.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that for Apple's code takes slightly different paths for initWithCoder and initWithFrame, and so its calling this method once NOT related to the placeholderstring.

So in my tests I had two of your labels, one created in code, one in the nib, both have a reasonably long Placeholder string.

The core problem relates to 'textRectForBounds:', since there is an additional message NOT related to the placeholder that shows up. Not only that, but the bounds is huge, and that is causing you to return a rect that is outside the bounds of the control. I don't know your code well enough to propose a solution, but at least you now know what to fix.

With this additional logging:

```
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    CGRect rect ;
    rect = [super textRectForBounds:bounds];
    NSLog(@"REAL textRectForBounds %@", NSStringFromCGRect(rect) );

    CGSize labelSize = [self.label.text sizeWithFont:self.label.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(MAX_LABEL_WIDTH, bounds.size.height)];
    CGSize textSize = [@"Test" sizeWithFont:self.font]; 

    NSLog(@"labelSize=%@ textSize=%@ bounds=%@", NSStringFromCGSize(labelSize), NSStringFromCGSize(textSize), NSStringFromCGRect(bounds));

    rect = CGRectMake(10 + labelSize.width,
                      (bounds.size.height-textSize.height)/2,
                      bounds.size.width - (20 + labelSize.width + ((self.showButton) ? BUTTON_WIDTH : 0)),
                      textSize.height);

NSLog(@"%@: textRectForBounds %@", type, NSStringFromCGRect(rect) );
    return rect;
}
```

What I'm seeing is this:

```
labelSize={0, 100} textSize={28, 18} bounds={{0, 0}, {100, 100}}
textRectForBounds {{10, 41}, {80, 18}}
```

So the system is passing in that 100x100 bounds for some reason, and your code then creates a rect that has the y offset 10 points below the textField. You will need to account for this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I set a breakpoint, and found that layoutSubviews is called (probably as a result of formatting code in the view controller and user-defined key-value pairs in the nib). I tried your solution for good measure, but still no text is drawn.

Comment: Ooops - I got too focused on getting the ...RectForBounds methods to appear and forgot about showing the text - I'll take a second look at my code. Can you clarify "no text" - what exactly do you have in the nib (a placeholder? Text?)

Comment: There is no text in the text fields to start with, but when I tap the field and begin typing, the text and cursor are not drawn. I can type and read back the value, just not see it. Also, when I press and hold the field, there is nothing in the magnifying glass.

Comment: Austin, I'm trying to help but overall design is yours. I did get the one case of a placeholder string to work by overriding the off-screen-rect that you computed. I suspect that if you add lots of logging as I did you can track down each case. I would guess that at various times the rectangle which is returned is out of the control bounds, or covered up by something else. By switching back and forth between your routine for textSize and using super, I could see where things changed.

Comment: Thanks. I was just trying to clarify what I meant by "no text." I think this may be a bug, because there is no good reason that textRectForBounds should be called with a 100x100 rect on a text field that is 39x300. I'll file a bug report with Apple and see what they say. In the meantime, I've worked around the issue by implementing `- (void)copy` to return a text field with the same background color, text, etc, and replacing the views loaded from nib with the copies.

Comment: My custom UITextField is also called with a rect of 100x100 in textRectForBounds: . Have you heard something from Apple regarding your bug?